# TabGroupActivity android app - after sign out prevent going back

Tags: android

I have an app that uses tab group activities.  All is working fine with the way the tabs open each activity within themselves, however my trouble is coming when the user logs out.  I have a dialog that confirms that the user wants to log out, and when they click YES it sends a http request to url that kills the session server side, clears some variables from the storepreferences and then starts the Login activity.  That all works great, but when the user is at the login screen at that point, if they hit back it takes them back to the activity they were on before they hit log out.  I've tried adding flags such as FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS, FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, none seem to work, they can still hit back and get to the previous activity.  So I've overridden the onBackPressed method on the Login screen to make it instead send the app to the background (moveTaskToBack(true)).  That seemed to work and when I hit back it goes to the home screen, but if I click the icon for my app, it resumes not at the login screen where I expected to, but on the activity before the user logged out.  Any ideas as to what I can try to make it so when the user signs out, it clears ALL previous activities and presents them with my login activity without the ability to go back?  Thank you in advance for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your minimum target is Honeycomb or higher, it's very easy.  If your minimum is lower, it gets slightly more complicated.  With Honeycomb, you can add a few flags to the intent, and it works fine.  In lower API levels, the only guaranteed way to do this that I have found is to launch an activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and have that activity launch your login activity and then finish.

```
@TargetApi( Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB )
private void logout() {

    Intent intent;
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {

        intent = new Intent( this, LoginActivity.class );
        intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
        startActivity( intent );
        finish();
    }
    else {

        intent = new Intent( this, HomeActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra( "logout", true );
        intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
        startActivity( intent );
        finish();
    }
}
```

In `HomeActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    boolean logout = getIntent().getBooleanExtra( "logout", false );
    if ( logout ) {
        startActivity( new Intent( this, LoginActivity.class ) );
        finish();
        return;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work so far, although at times the app closes completely rather than returning to login screen.  Marking as accepted for now until I find better solution.  Thank you James for your help!

Comment: I don't see how this could ever close the app completely.  In all scenarios you are starting a new `LoginActivity`.

Comment: James, your answer is most certainly correct.  The main class that holds my tabhost had extra code in the onDestory() method that was killing the app.  Removed and it is working perfectly.  Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the Back Press  Method, something to make it go out when it clicks on the back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

or you can redirect to a view after logout to a view with the option nohistory, this can be made by adding this line on the AndroidManifest where the new activity logout is defines

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: Tried both of these options and unfortunately it's still doing the same thing.  When I press back on the Login screen, it goes to home screen as expected, but when I click my app icon to relaunch, it resumes where the user was before logging out.

Comment: you did add the noHistory to your LoginActivity ?

Comment: Yes but it still resumed at the previous activity.  If you have any other thoughts, I'm up for trying.  Thank you for your help!!

Comment: when moving to the new activity try adding this line:

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);